# Baking normals with Multires modifier vs cage

Tags: texture-baking, baking, normal-map

Below you can see the baked normals for Cage and Multires.

Both yield almost identical results. But which of the two is more prefered? Is there a reason why I should use the elaborate cage method?

Rendered in Cycles.

Cage
[image: Cage]

Multires
[image: Multires]